# Identify Armenian romantic song by video?

Tags: identify-this-song, music-video, pop

I'm afraid I have almost no details. I saw a small part of an Armenian music video and really liked it, but because I don't speak Armenian I don't know how to locate it.

The video was recent. It opened with the singer - a handsome middle-aged man, black hair, small goatee - putting on a brightly-colored tie in a gaudy pink room. His wife/girlfriend, a blonde, looked on. He patted his small boy on the head. Romantic pop music.

And that's all I've got. I know it's very little to go on, but maybe somebody will recognize it!

Comment: Did you use the provided info for search yourself in Youtube and / or another source or did you have the link of the video that you're describing?

Comment: @Mauricio, I'm afraid my title is misleading - I don't have a link to the video. I meant to ask if anyone could identify this song based on my (admittedly meager) description of my memory of the video.

Comment: I understand now, please, edit your title and [Wlecome to Music Fans](http://musicfans.stackexchange.com/tour). If you remember the source of the video and/or more information _maybe you did your own research and you excluded other music themes_ you can also edit your question for add these info, Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked this question in April & not long ago stumbled on the video. It's Vonc Em Qez Sirum by Grigory Esayan.